# How to remove all the jars from a spring boot application using maven

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, build, war

I need to remove all the jars (the whole lib and lib-provided folders) from the war that I'm building using spring boot, since the web application will be deployed on Websphere, using commons shared libraries.

Is there any way to do that, since exclusions from the war plugin can't be used, and exclusions from the boot maven plugin are meant to be used punctual?

EDIT:

My current POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>artifactId</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>Application Name</name>
    <description>Application Description</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
        <powermock.version>1.6.5</powermock.version>
        <snippetsDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-snippets</snippetsDirectory>
        <hibernate.version>4.2.15.Final</hibernate.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- SPRING DEPENDENCIES -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-legacy</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- DATABASE RELATED DEPENDENCIES -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- TEST & DEVELOPEMENT DEPENDENCIES -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
            <version>${powermock.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
            <version>${powermock.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.restdocs</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-restdocs-mockmvc</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*Documentation.java</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.asciidoctor</groupId>
                <artifactId>asciidoctor-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-docs</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>process-asciidoc</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <backend>html</backend>
                            <doctype>book</doctype>
                            <attributes>
                                <snippets>${snippetsDirectory}</snippets>
                            </attributes>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-resources</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>
                                ${project.build.outputDirectory}/static/docs
                            </outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>
                                        ${project.build.directory}/generated-docs
                                    </directory>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: do not use the repackaging at all. Just a regular war file like you'd do without Spring Boot.

Comment: Not what I'm looking for..

Comment: well it's not clear what you're looking for. My point is that there's nothing Spring Boot specific about your use case. Just use the regular war if you want to deploy it in an environment that provides the libraries.So don't use the repackage and the regular feature of the `maven-war-plugin`.

Comment: @StephaneNicoll is right, you don't need spring-boot if what you want is deploying web application into any container. But if you insist, check my updated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean you want to exclude jars inside `your-project.war/WEB-INF/lib`,  then you could try to use `<scope>provided</scope>`.

Example

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

[This is example](https://github.com/xsalefter/test-lazy-hibernate/blob/so-40591255/pom.xml) for you.

**EDIT**

By looking and test your `pom.xml`, you could remove these lines:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
</plugin>
```

With that, I can't see lib-provided directory anymore.

HTH.

Comment: This is a partial solution to my problem, since everything goes inside lib-provided... I need to have a lighter war file...

Comment: What is a `lib-provided` folder? Where does it stay on your application?

Comment: When I build my application, inside WEB-INF, I have both lib and lib-provided. lib-provided contains all the jars that are tagged as provided in my pom.

Comment: Is this `lib-provided` physically exist in your project directory? Because AFAIK, standard maven project structure don't have any directory named `lib-provided`. Or, if you don't mind, put your pom.xml and any related maven file in your question. Remove any password or any sensitive data if exist.